# want to achieve rollup summary(SUM) using Aggregate functionss

Tags: apex, trigger, aggregate

**Compile Error:** 
*Expression must be a list type: SOBJECT:AggregateResult at line 7 column 36 
(this is line no7:manu.Total_Cost__c = Decimal.valueOf(ar[0].get('total'));)*

```
 trigger rollupfldsonManuf on Bottle__c (after insert, after update) 
 {
   Manufacuture__c manu = new Manufacuture__c();
   List<aggregateResult> results=[select Beverages__c,sum(cost__c) total from bottle__c group by Beverages__c];
   for (AggregateResult ar : results){
     if (ar[0].get('Beverages__c')=='Alcoholic beverages'){
         manu.Total_Cost__c=Decimal.valueOf(ar[0].get('total'));
        }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the below code

```
trigger rollupfldsonManuf on Bottle__c (after insert, after update) {
  Manufacuture__c manu = new Manufacuture__c();
  List<aggregateResult> results=[select Beverages__c,sum(cost__c) total from bottle__c group by Beverages__c];
   for (AggregateResult ar : results){
     if (String.valueof(ar.get('Beverages__c'))=='Alcoholic beverages'){
        manu.Total_Cost__c=Decimal.valueOf(ar.get('total'));
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the best example on how to use these aggregate results

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'd go a step further on this:

```
trigger rollupfldsonManuf on Bottle__c (after insert, after update) {
    Manufacuture__c manu = new Manufacuture__c();
    for (AggregateResult ar : [select sum(cost__c) total from bottle__c where Beverages__c = 'Alcoholic beverages' group by Beverages__c]){
        manu.Total_Cost__c = (decimal)ar.get('total'));
    }
}
```

If you only care about one specific value in beverages__c, limit the aggregate query to that value. This  limits the total number of rows queried to help avoid governor limits.